# Replace lowercase word in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

The pages on my site don't work if you access them by a url which is all lowercase

e.g.

mysite.com/product-category/mens doesn't show correctly

but

mysite.com/product-category/mens does show correctly.

I want to try the .htacess route first of all, but I can't get this to work. What i've tried is the following:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^/product-category/mens/(.*)$ ^/product-category/Mens/$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mens [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/Mens [R,L]
```

But i've very new to .htaccess files and after almost two hours of searching i've decided to ask for help.

Thanks in advance

*********ANSWER***********

Thanks Jon Lin for the solution:

```
RewriteRule ^product-category/mens/(.*)$ product-category/Mens/$1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mens(.*)$
RewriteRUle ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?Mens%1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first rule is close, you need to remove the leading slash:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^product-category/mens/(.*)$ ^/product-category/Mens/$1 [L,R]
```

and for the query string rule you need:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mens(.*)$
RewriteRUle ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?Mens%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: I just made a slight change for it to work, but it all came from the above!

I've addeded my final answer in the main question!Thanks